# html a click event use jquery

Tags: jquery

hi every I writed a line like this:

```
<a href="#">delete</a>
```

I want do some in js function when click this,so I use jQuery, and like this

```
$('a[href='#']').click(function(){
  alert("test");
  return false;
});
```

I use this to test, but it do best in Firefox, but can't work in IE, why? I could not find the error, could you help me thank you

Comment: Can you give the `<a>` element a class?

Answer (score 6):

single quote `$('a[href='#']')` is closing the string

```
$("a[href='#']").click(function(){
    alert("test");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of the quotes.

```
$("a[href='#']").click(function(){
  alert("test");
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are causing the problem.

```
$('a[href="#"]').click(function(){ alert("test"); return false; });
```

If you look closely, I have changed the single quotes around the `#` to double quotes.  If you use only single quotes, then JavaScript thinks you are trying to end the quoted string.  FireFox is catching the error (correctly) and does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I do it follow your advices,but it also didn't work in IE,so I changed the way,I use the span for href ,like this
test
and change the css for span,to made it had the style of href
Aslo think you very much